# Why cross line appear over the flutter Firebase instances

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When i want to use the Firestore instances of Firebase, then this cross line appeared, why???

[image: i]

Comment: Which firebase version you are using? Show your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: If you mouse hover on the strikked out lines, you will know wahy the compiler marks it as a warning and waht should be the fix

Answer (score 2):

**Firestore** is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Class Firestore is deprecated, use **FirebaseFirestore** instead.. You can install latest version of package library from https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/install

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

**getDocuments** is also deprecated and shouldn't be used. Deprecated in favor of `.get()`.

For more details check https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

You're using a very old version of the Firestore API for Flutter.  The latest SDK uses `FirebaseFirestore.instance`.  I suggest following the steps to integrate the Firebase SDK in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/), the continue with the [Firestore setup](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview).  You will have these dependencies (the latest as of today):

```
firebase_core: "^0.5.0"
cloud_firestore: "^0.14.0+2"
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, it's customary on Stack Overflow to upvote and mark as correct using the buttons on the left.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are spot on in how to fix it.

Why does it have a strikethrough (crossed out) though? Because it is marked as `@deprecated` in the libraries code.

Here is info from dart [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/Deprecated-class.html):

> The intent of the @Deprecated annotation is to inform users of a feature that they should change their code, even if it is currently still working correctly.
>
> A deprecated feature is scheduled to be removed at a later time,
> possibly specified in message. A deprecated feature should not be
> used, code using it will break at some point in the future. If
> existing code is using the feature it should be rewritten to not use
> the deprecated feature.

You can also do this is your own code when working with open source or a team, if you have plans on removing features, that way you let others know to avoid using it and that they should migrate to the replacements.